# sorting multi-dimensional array by comment_id == parent_id

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, anonymous-function

i have multi-dimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 32
            [article_id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 31
            [user_id] => 22
            [content] => dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
            [created_at] => 02-04-2021
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 30
            [article_id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 29
            [user_id] => 22
            [content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            [created_at] => 01-04-2021
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 31
            [article_id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 29
            [user_id] => 22
            [content] => Sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
            [created_at] => 02-04-2021
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 29
            [article_id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 0
            [user_id] => 22
            [content] => dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
            [created_at] => 01-04-2021
        )

)
```

and I try to get

```
Array
(
    [comment_id] => 29
    [article_id] => 5
    [parent_id] => 0
    [user_id] => 22
    [content] => dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
    [created_at] => 01-04-2021
    [comments] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [comment_id] => 31
                    [article_id] => 5
                    [parent_id] => 29
                    [user_id] => 22
                    [content] => Sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
                    [created_at] => 02-04-2021
                    [comments] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 32
                            [article_id] => 5
                            [parent_id] => 31
                            [user_id] => 22
                            [content] => dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
                            [created_at] => 02-04-2021
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [comment_id] => 30
                    [article_id] => 5
                    [parent_id] => 29
                    [user_id] => 22
                    [content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    [created_at] => 01-04-2021
                )

        )

)
```

based on [parent_id] == [comment_id]

I did try foreach loops with some if statements but I don't know how deep the multi-dimensional array going to be in future. and anonymous fc are not my friends yet :(
Anybody can give me a hint how to get around that.

Many thanks

Comment: Have a look at recursion.

Comment: Should comment_id 31 always come before comment_id 30 (as children of 29) or does it not matter?

Comment: thanks, it should really, but I see it as less problem then the one I have now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where references come in handy...

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'comment_id' => 32,
        'article_id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 31,
        'user_id' => 22,
        'content' => "dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing", 
        'created_at' => "02-04-2021"
    ],
    [
        'comment_id' => 30,
        'article_id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 29,
        'user_id' => 22,
        'content' => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
        'created_at' => "01-04-2021"
    ],
    [
        'comment_id' => 31,
        'article_id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 29,
        'user_id' => 22,
        'content' => "Sit amet consectetur adipisicing",
        'created_at' => "02-04-2021"
    ],
    [
        'comment_id' => 29,
        'article_id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'user_id' => 22,
        'content' => "dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing",
        'created_at' => "01-04-2021"
    ]
];

$references = [];
foreach ($input as &$entry) {
    $entry['comments'] = [];
    $references[$entry['comment_id']] = &$entry;
} 

$output = [];
array_walk($references, function(&$entry) use ($references, &$output) {
    if ($entry['parent_id'] != 0) {
        $references[$entry['parent_id']]['comments'][] = &$entry;
    } else {
        $output[] = &$entry;
    }
});

print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 29
            [article_id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 0
            [user_id] => 22
            [content] => dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            [created_at] => 01-04-2021
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 30
                            [article_id] => 5
                            [parent_id] => 29
                            [user_id] => 22
                            [content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                            [created_at] => 01-04-2021
                            [comments] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 31
                            [article_id] => 5
                            [parent_id] => 29
                            [user_id] => 22
                            [content] => Sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                            [created_at] => 02-04-2021
                            [comments] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [comment_id] => 32
                                            [article_id] => 5
                                            [parent_id] => 31
                                            [user_id] => 22
                                            [content] => dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                                            [created_at] => 02-04-2021
                                            [comments] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two steps:

1. Index your entries by comment ID
2. Loop over every entry and populate the `comments` of the parent entry with the current one, while making sure to remember which one is the root of your tree.

Code:

```
$arr_by_comment_id = array_column($arr, null, 'comment_id');

$root_entry = null;
foreach ($arr_by_comment_id as &$entry) {
    if ($entry['parent_id'] === 0) {
        $root_entry =& $entry;
    } elseif (array_key_exists($entry['parent_id'], $arr_by_comment_id)) {
        $arr_by_comment_id[$entry['parent_id']]['comments'][] = $entry;
    }
}
unset($entry);  // For safety (since references were used)

print_r($root_entry);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gSkH2)**